# ¿Se usa en español "paso en falso" como adaptación de "faux pas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

El otro día en una conversación alguien usó la expresión *faux pas* para indicar "una violación de las normas sociales o reglas de etiqueta" (definición de [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_pas)), dado que la conversación versaba sobre la vestimenta adecuada para asistir a un evento.

El caso es que no me suena haber visto mucho esa expresión con ese sentido en textos en español. Le he preguntado a la RAE si ese término estaba asentado en español y [me dicen que](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1020218058777022464)

> No, se emplea su versión española, «paso en falso».

El problema es que esa expresión ya existe en español [con otro sentido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S4wajTd#8MJJ2qx):

> **dar un paso en falso**
>
> 1. loc. verb. **dar un mal paso**.
>
> **dar un mal paso**
>
> 1. loc. verb. Sufrir un fallo al andar o al correr del que se sigue daño.
> 2. loc. verb. Hacer algo de lo que se sigue o puede seguirse detrimento.

La primera acepción es la literal, y la segunda parece una versión genérica del hecho de cometer un error en las reglas de etiqueta. Y de hecho me suena aún menos que *faux pas* para ese sentido.

Así pues, ¿se usa realmente en español "paso en falso" para indicar "una violación de las normas sociales o reglas de etiqueta", como hace el galicismo *faux pas*?

Answer (score 2):

Un *paso en falso* es cometer un error.
Un *faux pas* es llevar calcetines con sandalias.

No es un error, pero no es algo aceptado, pero por ser cuestiones similares en cuanto a "romper reglas", pues se pueden confundir.

Por ejemplo: ir a una entrevista de trabajo con calcetines con sandalias es tanto un *faux pas* como un *paso en falso*.

O sea ... el *paso en falso* requiere una intención (la cual falló) y el *faux pas* es solo un tipo de "paso en falso".

Así que creo que un *faux pas* en español lo traduciríamos como "hacer el ridículo".

No sé ... Yo soy muy españolista (de español, no de España) y no me gusta utilizar expresiones de otros idiomas cuando bien podemos expresarlas en español o a nuestra propia manera. Decir ***faux pas*** me parece un *faux pas* (ridículo) y tal vez a otros también les parezca un *Faux pas* (insultante), o a otros también les parezca un *faux pas* (inculto) o a otros que se lo tomen también como *faux pas* (inmaduro), a los que les parezca un *faux pas* (vulgar) y los que se lo tomen con un verdadero *faux pas* (lo que los franceses quisieron decir).

Comment: pero aunque me guste mucho el español.. Por favor dejad de decir ONDA VITAL

Comment: No entiendo el comentario de lo de la "onda vital".

Comment: *Pas* es *paso*.  *Étape* es *fase, etapa*.

Comment: @aparente001 tiene sentido !, eliminado el ultimo parrafo

Comment: Estoy tratando de recordar cómo oía usar esta expresión en Francia -- creo que *faux pas* era suave en comparación con *bêtise*. // Acabo de recordar *babosada*, voy a agregar a mi respuesta.

Comment: Excelente último párrafo +1

Answer (score 1):

Creo que en lenguaje un poco formal sí se usa.  Por el contexto se podrá distinguir entre la acepción literal y la figurativa.

Las alternativas:

1. Cambiar la estructura de la frase y usar el verbo **meter la pata**
2. **metedura/metida de pata**
3. Informal: **tontería**
4. Muy informal: **babosada**
5. Muy informal y muy fuerte: **estupidez**

El (1) es lo más común, creo.

Mi favorito: *babosada*.  Y yo cometo muchas.

Comment: Al menos en España es más habitual **metedura de pata** que **metida de pata**.